# Set dateformat once, so jquery and jqueryUI date picker use that date format

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization

Is there a way for me to set the date format once to 'dd/MM\yyyy' and then have jquery's ui datepicker use that date?

I don't want to set the date format everytime I use the datepicker.

I am getting the format from a server-side config setting, so I can output this on every page request to a js variable on the page.

Answer (score 2):

[$.datepicker.setDefaults( settings )](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/setDefaults)

Comment: but I need it for all dates, not just what datepicker uses, isn't there a more generic solution?

Comment: @Blankman i believe there is not. Each jQuery plugin uses it's own configuration.